# Upwork no project still need to pay taxes

Tags: freelance-websites, taxes

How does paypal work with upwork do they just send the money to Paypal and if you can't get project you still have to pay for taxes from upwork?

Comment: I hope someone can answer you. However, I don't understand the context. SFAIK, I pay taxes (in the US) only on income. Lacking income (Paypal or otherwise), I expect to pay no taxes. Do you have indication otherwise?

Comment: I was told by upwork I don't need to pay taxes if I can't any project  on upwork I was told.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically- if its income, its taxable. you will need to report it and pay appropriate taxes.

Upwork has its own payment system. i would recommend using that instead of Paypal because Upwork has a good escrow system to ensure you get paid. I have had good arbitration with Upwork also